# Cant create table using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-management-studio

When I try to add table do database I get window with this error:

```
===================================

Nieokreślony błąd. //that means Unspecified Error
 (MS Visual Database Tools)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataTools.Interop.IDTTableDesignerFactory.NewTable(Object dsRef, Object pServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.TableDesignerNode.CreateDesigner(IDTDocToolFactoryProvider factoryProvider, IVsDataConnection dataConnection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.CreateDesigner()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
```

What can I do to be able to edit database?

Comment: Can you connect to the database?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to database. I can execute query. I can't create table via visual editor (RMB->New Table)